# undo-tree is not able to load the latest changes from previous emacs daemon session

Tags: undo-tree-mode

I can access all the changes in the `undo-tree` during `emacs --daemon` session. But when it session is killed and new `emacs --daemon` is started `undo-tree-visualize` is shown clean.

- I have applied following solution [Is there any way to have Emacs save your undo history between sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44326911/2402577) in emacs v27.2

`minimal.el`:

```
(defun my-save-all ()
       (interactive)
       (let ((message-log-max nil)
             (inhibit-message t))
         (save-some-buffers t)))

(defun save-all ()
  (interactive)
  (my-save-all)
  (bk-kill-buffers "magit: ebloc-broker")
  (bk-kill-buffers "__init__.py")
  (bk-kill-buffers "*helm"))

(define-key ctl-x-map "\C-s" 'save-all)

(global-undo-tree-mode 1)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))
```

I have observe that `undo-tree` history is saved under `~/.emacs.d/undo` as hidden files but they won't loaded when new `emacs ---daemon` is started.

simple scenario:

```
$ (&>/dev/null emacs --daemon -nw &)
$ command emacsclient -tqu doo.py 
# - make changes check `undo-tree-visualize`
# - kill `emacs —daemon`

# restart `emacs daemon`
$ (&>/dev/null emacs --daemon -nw &)
$ command emacsclient -tqu doo.py 
# apply: M-x undo-tree-visualize

# The undo-tree is empty
```

[Q] Is there anyway to force `emacs` daemon to load the already saved `unto-tree` history for the opened file.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue using Emacs 26.1 in the terminal on OSX 10.6.8.  The command line option `--fg-daemon` seems to do nothing for me, so I used `--daemon` instead.  **STEP #1**:  `/path/to/emacs --daemon -nw`  **STEP #2**:  Open a new tab in the terminal and run the command:  `/path/to/emacsclient -tqu doo.py`, then type in random text into the buffer and then `M-x save-buffer`  **STEP #3**:  Close the terminal entirely including both tabs.  Open the Activity Monitor and quit the daemon, which in my case had a process name of `Emacs-x86_64-10_10`.  .... continued below

Comment: ... continued from comment above... **STEP #4**:  Repeat steps #1 and #2 above, and then `M-x undo-tree-visualize` and I see the history created when the buffer was saved in step #1 above.  **STEP #5**:  I inspect `~/.emacs.d/undo/` and see a file named `.!Users!HOME!doo.py.~undo-tree~`

Comment: Perhaps you expect Emacs to save the undo-tree history file without saving the buffer?  If so, then that is the issue; i.e., the history file is created when saving the buffer.  The history file is read when the buffer is opened, provided a history file already exists.  There are also checks to match the history file with a SHA code embedded in the history file based upon the buffer contents ..., as well as the file name.  [FYI:  There is a bug in the master undo-tree repository that I've never reported, which affects a narrowed buffer being saved -- the SHA is of the narrowed buffer only.]

Comment: Ah `--fg-daemon` was for macOS side I am using `--daemon` for linux as well, updated the question for clearity. Interestingly I can see file `!Users!HOME!doo.py.~undo-tree~` and it is kept updated, file but it is not read when daemon is restarted, like the tree starts with a single root node (`X`) no matter what :( Please see my updated question for how I save my buffers, not sure would it affect anything.

Comment: Example save file: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/59dce1e019a23664d8072408ecb7ec63 but it does not properly read from the new emacs daemon session :(

Comment: The function `undo-tree-load-history` generates error messages if the history file fails to load.  You may wish to begin your debugging of this issue by placing an additional line of code immediately *above* the comment ("`;; attempt to read undo-tree from FILENAME`") to ensure that the history files is being processed and then check the `*Messages*` buffer for clues when the problem occurs.  E.g., add a line like this:  `(message "filename:  %s" filename)`.  While debugging, I would remove the byte-compiled version of `undo-tree.elc` if it exists.

Comment: Hm it says `filename does not exist; could not load undo-tree history`, seems like it is not properly saved when session is killed. But during the daemon session it can jump to history see the history within the session so I am not sure where it is saved during the emacs session

Comment: When `undo-tree-mode` is active in the working buffer, it uses a buffer-local variable called `buffer-undo-tree` to store and read-back the undo history (e.g., to populate the undo-tree visualization buffer), and data is periodically gathered from the built-in variable `buffer-undo-list`.  The undo-tree history file is used in these circumstances:  (1) when the buffer is opened and the undo-tree history is being restored, (2) when saving the buffer in order to update the undo-tree history file (via the `write-file-functions` hook), (3) when killing a buffer (via the `kill-buffer-hook`. ...

Comment: ... After running **STEP #1** and **STEP #2** in the first comment of this thread -- ensuring that you call `M-x save-buffer` (rather than your own custom save function), verify that the undo-tree history file has been created and/or updated in the directory `~/.emacs.d/undo` -- check the file stamp to see if the modification date/time coincides with the moment you called `M-x save-buffer`, and then proceed to kill the daemon and proceed from there.  Perhaps your custom save-buffer function is not really saving the buffer you are working in?

Comment: Thank you for your patience after hours of debugging I found the responsible function.  `async-undo-tree-save-history`, which is taken from here(https://github.com/mpereira/.emacs.d/blob/master/configuration.org#asynchronous-undo-tree-history-save). I think I have to integrate it with my save function

Comment: To be clear I put my debug solution into answer. Please feel free to edit for a better solution. Since I was using my own save function, I believe `after-save-hook` messes up the saving undo-tree history.

Comment: It appears that you have chosen to use the `emacs-async` library by John Wiegley, with the function `async-start` running a separate instance / process of Emacs to run certain commands in `-batch`, in this case to save the undo-tree history file.  In your answer below, you stated that you "**un**commented" a section of code containing hooks (one of which calls an async custom function), and then you expressly call the same async function in your custom `save-all` function, which implies you are running the async function twice -- once with the `after-save-hook` and once again with `save-all`.

Comment: Ah sorry for typo, I have **commented** code piece starting with `(with-eval-after-load "undo-tree"`

Comment: When you "comment **out**" (i.e., `;;;`) the `(with-eval-after-load ... ` statement, the default behavior of `undo-tree.el` is to add `undo-tree-save-history-from-hook` to the `write-file-functions` hook.  So, when you call your custom `save-all` function, you first get the default behavior when `save-some-buffers` does its thing and Emacs runs the `write-file-functions` hook that calls `undo-tree-save-history-from-hook`, and then you call the `async-undo-tree-save-history` function (which I am unable to verify whether that even works as advertised).  Thus, you save the history file **twice**.

Comment: Got it all of this is beyond my knowledge to handle :) I think my best option is not to use `async-undo-tree-save-history`. Or can I just remove `(async-undo-tree-save-history)` under my `save-all ()` function?

Comment: I would recommend that you try living with the default behavior of `undo-tree` and *not* use `async-undo-tree-save-history`.  If you must use `async-undo-tree-save-history` because the default behavior of undo-tree is problematic for you (e.g., waiting an extra second or so when saving files with a large undo history), then you will want to ensure that `undo-tree-save-history-from-hook` is only called one time.  I have no idea why the author of `async-undo-tree-save-history` chose the `after-save-hook` and I have no idea why that solution was not working for you either.

Comment: The function `save-some-buffers` may result in saving *multiple* buffers where `undo-tree-mode` is active.  If so, then you want to save the undo-tree history using a hook such as the `write-file-functions` hook so that the history gets saved for each applicable file as `save-some-buffers` does its thing.  **Example**:  You call `save-some-buffers` and there are three (3) *modified* buffers using `undo-tree-mode` that get saved -- you want each of those buffers to create and/or update the undo-tree history files.  Thus, do *not* expressly call `async-undo-tree-save-history` within `save-all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to add following piece of code `async-undo-tree-save-history ()` at below, which was the main cause of the error. Since I wrote my own `save ()` function `after-save-hook` hook `(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'async-undo-tree-save-history)` does not properly save the `undo-tree` history.

I have **commented** following section:

```
(with-eval-after-load "undo-tree"
  (remove-hook 'write-file-functions #'undo-tree-save-history-from-hook)
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'async-undo-tree-save-history))
```

and updated my init.el file as follows:

```
(defun save-all ()
  (interactive)
  (my-save-all)
  (async-undo-tree-save-history)  ;; <== added here
```

---

- `async-undo-tree-save-history ()` function is taken from [Asynchronous undo-tree history save](https://github.com/mpereira/.emacs.d/blob/master/configuration.org#asynchronous-undo-tree-history-save):

> ````
> ((file-name (buffer-file-name)))
>     (async-start
>      `(lambda ()
>         (if (stringp ,file-name)
>             (list 'ok
>                   (list :output (with-output-to-string
>                                   (add-to-list
>                                    'load-path
>                                    ,async-undo-tree-save-history-cached-load-path)
>                                   (require 'undo-tree)
>                                   (find-file ,file-name)
>                                   (undo-tree-save-history-from-hook))
>                         :messages (with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
>                                     (buffer-string))))
>           (list 'err
>                 (list :output "File name must be string"
>                       :messages (with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
>                                   (buffer-string))))))
>      `(lambda (result)
>         (let ((outcome (car result))
>               (messages (plist-get (cadr result) :messages))
>               (output (plist-get (cadr result) :output))
>               (inhibit-message t))
>           (message
>            (cond
>             ((eq 'ok outcome)
>              "undo-tree history saved asynchronously for %s%s%s")
>             ((eq 'err outcome)
>              "error saving undo-tree history asynchronously for %s%s%s")
>             (:else
>              "unexpected result from asynchronous undo-tree history save %s%s%s"))
>            ,file-name
>            (if (string= "" output)
>                ""
>              (format "\noutput:\n%s" output))
>            (if (string= "" messages)
>                ""
>              (format "\nmessages:\n%s" messages))))))
>     nil))
>
> (with-eval-after-load "undo-tree"   (remove-hook 'write-file-functions
> #'undo-tree-save-history-from-hook)   (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'async-undo-tree-save-history)) ```
> ````